# Flutter Shortcuts physical key is pressed on a different logical key

Tags: android, flutter, keyset

I build flutter app for android TV, but I have issue with the IR remote
when I press OK key

> A KeyUpEvent is dispatched, but the state shows that the physical key
> is pressed on a different logical key. If this occurs in real
> application, please report this bug to Flutter. If this occurs in unit
> tests, please ensure that simulated events follow Flutter's event
> model as documented in `HardwareKeyboard`. This was the event:
> KeyUpEvent#f6347(physicalKey: PhysicalKeyboardKey#70077(usbHidUsage:
> "0x00070077", debugName: "Select"), logicalKey:
> LogicalKeyboardKey#00101(keyId: "0x200000101", keyLabel: "Control
> Right", debugName: "Control Right"), character: null, timeStamp:
> 0:00:08.820516, synthesized) and the recorded logical key
> LogicalKeyboardKey#0050c(keyId: "0x10000050c", keyLabel: "Select",
> debugName: "Select")

````
  shortcuts: <LogicalKeySet, Intent>{
    LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.select,): const ActivateIntent(),
  },```
````

Answer (score 0):

after many searches and tests, i reached the following and worked well.

in **hardware_keyboard.dart** search for **void _assertEventIsRegular** method and add the following before the `if (event is KeyDownEvent)`

added script:

```
if (event.physicalKey == PhysicalKeyboardKey.controlRight) {
         return true;
      }
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35046494)